# To CSS Style on the image uploaded on a Post under Content Section

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have uploaded a media picture to a post the HTML I saw as such

```
<a href="http://localhost/self/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/pic1.png"><img src="http://localhost/self/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/pic1.png" alt="pic1" width="260" height="260" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-204" />
```

How do I css style on this image? I can't use class="alignnone size-full wp-image-204" because on the next new post, that class name could be different.  All my post will have exactly one image and will be in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

In most themes you will be able to target every image in all your posts with the following css:

```
.type-post img { PUT CSS STYLES HERE }
```

This may not work, however, depending on the theme you're using, and whether or not your new styles conflict with higher-priority css. If you post a link to your website I can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: if it's custom type, for example, rating type, I could do .type-rating img { ...}

Comment: Generally, yes. If you post a link I can help you more.